# Vertical Align with display:table-cell enclosed in display: table not working

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

This is my first question so appologies if the format is wrong.

I've tried every method I've found on stack overflow but I still cannot get this content to display vertically in the middle.

CSS:

```
div.img-wrapper {
  display: table;
  height: 232px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
div.cover {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 232px;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}
```

HTML Markup:

```
<div class="img-wrapper">
  <img alt="" src="img2.jpg">
  <div class="cover">
    <img alt="" src="img1.png">
    <span class="product-name">Product Name</span>
    <span class="product-sub">Sub Line</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm using `position:absolute` as the `.cover` div rolls over the img to display product information.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks in advance.

Will

Comment: Do you need to use `position:absolute`?

Comment: I'm using `position:absolute` as the `.cover` div rolls over the img to display product information.

Comment: Does this work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/2pPHW/ I can't get it to center with `position:absolute`

Comment: I've tried using an outer container just for the position but then the table/table-cell wont go to 100% width. The Fiddle didn't work for me :(

Comment: I edited the fiddle.. check it now :)

Comment: In the future, if your question allows you to do so, show what you have so far tried and create a JSFiddle or a Codepen example of your code so that you are replicating the error for others to see. It also gives them an easy place to try things to resolve your problem facilitating a speedier resolution.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisSpittles I'll bare that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my attempt for it. An `outter-container` is needed because the table won't cover the page's `width` and `height` on it's own

Try this:

```
#outter-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
#img-wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#cover {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2pPHW/)

Comment: getting there, I've implemented your code and now I've got the problem with the `display:table`/`display:table-cell` not reaching 100% of the `outter-container`

Comment: I've actually sorted it now by moving the img2.jpg outside of the img-wrapper which was causing the table to squish. I'll mark your answer as correct and thanks for your help!